# Help with Insert Trigger that does lookup in another table (object)

Tags: apex, trigger

I have written a trigger (ListingAgent) trying to match fields from different objects, Opportunity and Agent.  On the Opportunity page if the Listing Agent ID from LR (Listing_Agent_ID_From_LR__c) has a ID that matches an Agent ID from the Agent Object , I want the Agent Name (Name) to be populated in the Listing Agent Field. 
I get 87% coverage but an error for the last line. Does someone see a problem with the code?  I can not see it. Please help.  Thank you

```
trigger Listingagent on Opportunity (before insert) {
    Set<String> lagid=new set<string>();
    for(opportunity o :Trigger.new){
        //if(o.listing_Agent_ID_From_LR__c != NULL)      
            lagid.add(o.Listing_Agent_ID_From_LR__c);
    }

    Map<String, String>matchid=new Map<String, String>();

    For(Agent__c ag: [select Agent_ID__c,
               Name
               from Agent__c 
               where Agent_ID__c 
                IN: lagid]){
        matchid.put(ag.Agent_ID__c, ag.Name);
    }
    For(Opportunity o : Trigger.new){
        if(matchid.containskey(o.Listing_Agent_ID_From_LR__c))
            o.Listing_Agent__c = matchid.get(o.Listing_Agent_ID_From_LR__c);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting/

Comment: Is Agency_ID__c a lookup field? You can make your Map<ID, String> instead. Maybe you are seeing a datatype conversion issue

Comment: When I run the in the Developer Console the last line is red.  I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: The Agent ID is not a look a field.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not explain correctly.  I do not get an error the last line is not covered in the trigger.  I am not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Can you post the test class?

Answer (score 0):

Not a 100% sure, but is Agent__c record present or accessible in test class?

Comment: Yes, it is accessible.  I am just not sure why the list line is not covered in the trigger.

Comment: Need to look at the test class code. Can you share it?

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help.  I have learned so much from your questions. The field was created but not on the page in the sandbox.  That is why it was not working.